# PostgreSQL: Select 2 or more records with the same id given a column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a column called **id**. The table name is called **names**.
I need to show all the id's that have one or more records on the table, and the corresponding fields on the table.
The search criteria is **WHERE org = 'A'**. If I search just for **org = 'A'** then I will show only those records. I need to be able to also show the other records with the same **id**.

I tried

```
SELECT id, name, state, org
FROM names
WHERE 
HAVING count(org) > 2
GROUP BY id, name, state, org
```

**names table**

| id | name | state | org |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | John | GA | A |
| 111 | April | FL | B |
| 112 | Max | GA | A |
| 113 | Alex | NC | C |
| 114 | Steve | SC | A |
| 114 | Rachel | AL | B |
| 114 | Brad | TN | D |

**Desired output**

| id | name | state | org |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | John | GA | A |
| 111 | April | FL | B |
| 114 | Steve | SC | A |
| 114 | Rachel | AL | B |
| 114 | Brad | TN | D |

Thanks

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, no records or fields. (Those are other stuff, don't mix things up.)

Comment: The order should be: SELECT ... FROM ... [ WHERE ] ... GROUP BY ... HAVING... [ ORDER BY ].

Comment: However, since you want complete rows back, skip the GROUP BY, instead use a window function query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be:

```
with tmp as (
  select names.*,
        count(*) over (partition by id) as same_id_count
  from names
)
select id, name, state, org 
from tmp
where same_id_count > 1 and id in (select distinct id 
                                   from names 
                                   where org = 'A');
```

Details:

- `tmp` CTE query helps calculate the number of rows with the same `id`,
  with the help of `count()` window function;
- in the outer query you filter the rows by `'A'` `org`-filter and the `same_id_count > 1` filter.

**[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gMXrTSHf)**

Comment: There is no org = 'A' filter in this query.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai thank you for noticing! I've updated my query.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the ids with more than one record and then use them to query

```
SELECT * from names where id in (SELECT id from names GROUP BY id having COUNT(id)>1 );
```

Comment: There is no org = 'A' filter in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the existence of org = A records and then fetch the matching id records. Then filter the records having more than 1 count -

```
SELECT id, name, state, org
  FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id) cnt
          FROM names n1
         WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                        FROM names n2
                       WHERE n1.id = n2.id
                         AND n2.org = 'A'
                     )
       ) x
 WHERE cnt > 1;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/JW8mB_BE)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to select 2 or more records with the same id given a column value we can use the following query

```
SELECT id, name, state, org
FROM names
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM names
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2
);
```

The following query will first select all the id's that have one or more records on the table, and the corresponding fields on the table. Then, it will use the IN operator to filter the results to only include rows with those id's.

This will give the same output as the desired output displayed in your question.

Comment: It doesn't look like you addressed the question.